# php banner queue fifo

Tags: php, queue, fifo, banner-ads

I'm just starting to put ad on my website and I would like to be able to give 1000 view to ad_a , 2000 to ad_b and let say 10000 to ad_c.

If only one page was view at the time it would be easy to update a DB and work out how many are left to view for each ad, but serval pages can be access at the same time and this make things more complicated.

I was thinking of writting a queue to manage it and request will be done one by one on the database. I'm not sure if this is the best idea or not, never done this kind of coding and I'm looking for a line of conduct, logical steps, what kind of table to create in the db if there is specification.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: A queue would work just fine indeed. When it's empty, refill it with "banners to show" according to the rules.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Memcached to store the current count of views. Memcached is fast and light, you will not have performance problems. Also, something more complicated would be to have a "queue", as you say, and some parallel process updates it putting in there what banner to show, so you could mix them up.

Comment: I was looking for something like that, sounds really good I will read the doc and see how it's going.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that one page may be viewed many times at once doesn't have to be a problem, that's why [LOCK TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) is for.

```
LOCK TABLES ads WRITE;
SELECT ad_id FROM ads WHERE ad_views_remaining > 0 LIMIT 1;
UPDATE ads SET ad_views_remaining = ad_views_remaining -1 WHERE ad_name = THAT_AD_ID_YOU_SELECTED_BEFORE;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

This way no one can read the table until it's updated.
(this example is for MySQL, I'm sure that most other RDBMSs support locks as well)

Comment: Memcached seems to be a good option, but i've completly forgot about table locks, this would be much easier to implement! I will have go as well! Thx guys for your help!

Comment: Dude, you can just use transactions. But then you'll have a bottleneck.

Comment: Not always, for example if you're running on MyISAM, you're screwed.

Answer (score 0):

What about rand?

```
$r = rand(1, 13);
if ( $r == 1 )
    echo 'ad_a';
if ( $r > 1 and $r < 4 )
    echo 'ad_b';
if ( $r > 3 )
    echo 'ad_c';
```